# How to resolve Query String Cache issue in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, query-string

In my ASP.NET web site i am loading a page with a query string parameter attached to process something based on this query string information in the page load event.These query string parameters are different to each and everyone. Now my problem is some users are getting previously logged users query string values. That means may be the query string values are being Cached. How to resolve this issue.I even tried to remove Query String values immediately after getting its value in the page load event itself but no luck and the problem still persists.

Comment: Where do you suspect the query string are cached? Server side or client side?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete the quersting value on the page load event of the page. You cannot avoid user caching the url with query string in their browser. However what you should do is on the page load you need to validate whether the query string value is still valid or not. You will have to implement a mechanism according to your business logic, to validate the query string value. This is not only becuase of the querystring value being stored as favorites and browsed later, but also some malicious user might try to change the querstring value and try to see the information which they are not supposed to see

Other option could be that instead of passing the value as query string you can use session variables to pass the data from one page to another, if you need this value only for short time. You can clear the session value as soon as you read it.

Comment: Hey @Kiran Hegde thanks for answer. But i can not avoid using Query String as per our client requirements.However here the querystring value will be dynamically created for every user and i cannot validate the Query string value here as its coming from a different domain and these pages will be displayed in another page with the help of iframe. So can you tell me the root cause for this

Comment: Does the parent page has output cache configured? If so then it will always use the same url for IFRAME until the cache is invalidated

Comment: Hey @Kiran Hegde i checked that url is completely correct for every different user.However the page is getting previous Query String value...